# How to stream mp3 file from a SQL Server database in ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I stream mp3 files from a SQL Server database to an ASP.NET MVC view in C#?

I am able to retrieve the file from the database successfully but I do not
know what data needs to be passed to the view and what properties I need to 
set. I have tried playing with the data-sources in the view but still get a
"no file found" when I run the application.

I am not sure what the datasource should be. When I set the datasource to a path to a mp3 file locally, it works fine.

When I run the application I get a "No file found"

ASP.NET MVC controller:

```
using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        var mp3 = new Mp3Files
                {
                    DATA = (Byte[])dr["DATA"],
                    DATASCOURCE = dr
                };
        list.Add(mp3);
    }

    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Mp3FilesList.Add(item);
    }

    return View("Loops", "_Layout", Mp3FilesList);
}
```

View:

```
<div data-thumb="Scripts/img/adg3.jpg" data-type="audio" 
     class="audioplayer-tobe skin-wave " 
     data-source="@item.DATASCOURCE" data-
     scrubbg="../Scripts/waves2/adg3_mp3.png" data-
     scrubprog="Scripts/waves2/wavesprog.png" data-
     playfrom="last">
```

`Mp3Files` class:

```
{
    public int AUDIO_ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string CONTENT_TYPE { get; set; }
    public string BPM { get; set; }
    public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
    public Byte[] DATA { get; set; }
    public DbDataReader DATASCOURCE { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is quite old but as someone might come here after google research, I will share the way I've solved.

You have two options: by MVC (unfriendly if you have a lot of sounds to include in your page) or JQuery (you can create a loading animation to give user a friendly wait message or spinner, for example).

**OPTION 1 - MVC** (*I've used the name of your View (Loops) and the code you posted*):

```
public ActionResult Loops()
{
    PageViewModel result = new PageViewModel();
    IDataReader dr = null; // some SQL Search
    result.Files = new List<Mp3File>();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
        result.Files.Add(new Mp3File()
        {
           Id = int.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString()),
           Name = dr["Name"].ToString(),
           ContentType = dr["ContentType"].ToString(), //must be something like audio/mp3 for example
           Category = dr["Category"].ToString(),
           Data = (Byte[])dr["Data"]
        });
    }

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then, in your CSHTML file you loop through the files property of your ViewModel and point the data to the source of your audio HTML Element:

```
if (Model.Files?.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="list">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Files.Count; i++)
    {
        <!-- AUDIO ITEM -->
        <label class="item">
            <span class="title"><i class="far fa-file-audio"></i> @Model.Files[i].Name</span>
            <audio controls>
                <source src="@Model.Files[i].Data" type="@Model.Files[i].ContentType" />
            </audio>
        </label>
    }
    </div>
}
```

**JQuery Solution**: In my personal opinion, this options is better because it is more user friendly and don't cause a long waiting white page:

1) If possible, store your files in your web server as the loading process will be way faster;

2) Create one HTTP Get Method in your Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetFiles()
    {
         PageViewModel result = new PageViewModel();
         IDataReader dr = null; // some SQL Search
         result.Files = new List<Mp3File>();

         while (dr.Read())
         {
             result.Files.Add(new Mp3File()
             {
                Id = int.Parse(dr["Id"].ToString()),
                Name = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                ContentType = dr["ContentType"].ToString(), //must be something like audio/mp3 for example
                Category = dr["Category"].ToString(),
                Data = (Byte[])dr["Data"],
                Url = $"{Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)}/assets/audio/{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dr["Name"].ToString())}.mp3" //in case you stored your file in your web server
              });
          }

          return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

3) Create a javascript function in your CSTHML page that will load your files

```
//In this example I'm using local JS for JQuery and Bootstrap. But you can use the way you prefer (CDN or NPM for example)
<!-- SCRIPTS -->
<script src="~/assets/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadFiles();
    });

    function loadFiles() {

        //here I'm referencing a DIV tag that uses the spinner.js has the following content:
        $("#spinner").show(); 

            //<div class="wrapper-loading" id="spinner" style="display:none;">
            //    <span class="spinner-double-section-far"></span>
            //</div>

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: "GetFiles",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                $("#spinner").hide(); //stop spinner

                if (data) {
                    $("#audioContainer").show();

                    data.Files.forEach(audio => {
                        var newAudio = '<label class="item">';
                        newAudio += '<span class="title"><i class="far fa-file-audio"></i>' + audio.Name + '</span>';
                        newAudio += '<audio controls><source src="' + audio.Url + '" type="audio/mp3"/>';
                        newAudio += '</audio></label>';
                        $("#audioContainer").append(newAudio); //JQuery command to insert new HTML into some Element
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                $("#spinner").hide(); //stop spinner
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

That's all I needed to put some audio files in my page using the standard AUDIO HTML control that has embedded controls like play, pause, etc.

Good luck and hope it helps you.